# Scale fishing rod in one direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, scaling, unity3d-2dtools

This may seem like a repeated question. I have a fishing rod and a hook at the end of the rod. Where ever I click on the screen, based on the y index of the click I move my hook to that position. So say for instance my hook is currently at (2,3) if I click at (400, 9) I move my hook to (2,9). So i just move it vertically based on the click.

This is working fine. Now based on the position of the hook I want to scale my fishing rod accordingly. So once im done positioning my hook I call the following ScaleRod(). The rod sprite has a pivot at top-left, and not center. I want to rod to scale only vertically. Below is my code for the same:

```
         void scaleRod() {
         //get current size of the fishing rod
         var rodLength = System.Math.Abs(renderer.bounds.size.y); 
         //Get distance between the hook and the rod based on y coordinates.
         float hookRodDistance = (System.Math.Abs(transform.position.y) + rodLength) - System.Math.Abs(hookObject.transform.position.y);
         hookRodDistance =  System.Math.Abs(hookRodDistance);
         //Calculate the scale factor
         float scaleFactor = hookRodDistance / rodLength;
         //Scale  the rod        
         transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, scaleFactor * transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z );
        }
```

The function is giving me wierd output on the scale.

Can someone please help. Have been stuck for a while on this. Thank you so much.

Edit: Adding images for better idea about the issue.

[image: Initial setup]

[image: First Click]

[image: Second Click]

Comment: Well, you've tried all the code possible.. not sure why you're asking here - clearly it's not possible! ... But seriously can you explain what "wierd output" is exactly?

Comment: The scaled length is much more than expected. 

Iv tried this : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/656423/how-can-i-scale-my-object-in-one-direction.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/120081/how-can-i-scale-my-object-quotupwardsquot.html

Comment: I think this is a case where a picture might be helpful..

Comment: @Blorgbeard I have added images to the questions

Comment: Please don't use unity tag got questions related to Unity game engine. There's unity3d tag for that.

Comment: Is your Hook somehow a child of the Rod Line?

Comment: Then it is going to cause some problem. I think this is what is happening to your game.

Your Parent is Stretching so by default. If you made a child it will make your Child attached to its center Pivot point of the parent. Now looking in your code, you're trying to overwrite the problem. But in MonoDevelop(Unity3D Engine) It is still implementing its own logic to whenever the Parent is Scaled, the child will stick to its parent Pivot point.

Just a pointer that could lead you to something. Never hurts to check out. Try to remove it as a child.

Answer (score 0):

I think your maths is off, let's plug some numbers into your code. Say the pivot point of the rod is at Y 0 (therefore the `transform.position.y` will be 0), the rod is length 1, and the hook is at Y 2. Currently, your `hookRodDistance` would be 1, the `scaleFactor` would be 1, and the `localScale` wouldn't change the size at all, despite the rod being 1 unit too short.

Instead, you could just work out how long you want the rod to be, and set the `localScale` Y to that length:

```
var desiredLength = System.Math.Abs(transform.position.y - hookObject.transform.position.y);
transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, desiredLength, transform.localScale.z );
```

Comment: thank you for the code, your reasoning seems legit. But I feel setting the localScale.y = desiredLen is causing the rod to scale well over the needed scaling. It is similar to the 3rd screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Could it be that your sprite is not the same size as the GameObject it's attached to?